# HTTP Status 500 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat, servlets

HTTP Status 500 - 
type Exception report  message  description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.  exception  org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:   An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files  Stacktrace:  org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)     org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)     org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:469)  org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)  org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)  org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)  org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.27 logs.

Plz help me friends how to solve this problem . I have got this problem when i open webpage (localhost:8085)soon after installing tomcat (i have set classpath tooo ) .Plz kindly send any  answers to rakeshdatla999@gmail.com...

Comment: Is it   problem of  your jsp or jsp from standard tomcat installation?

Comment: Any suggestions on this. I'm getting the same thing, but in my case I do know that the issue is with Java8.

Answer (score 0):

Possible mismatch between version of Tomcat and version of JDK/JRE. It happened to me on Mac with Java 8 and Tomcat 7.2*. Had to install and use Tomcat 7.5*

Answer (score 0):

I was using Windows 10 OS for developing applications in TM1 Performance Modeller as part of Academic projects. 
I had been trying to run pmpsvc services of IBM Performance Modeller. I was getting the error "**unable to logon to pmpsvc**". 
Also, when I was trying to logon to Application Server in my browser, I was getting the same error that you've posted here.

**What I think(after going through different posts in the search results of Google and Stackoverflow):** There is some compatibility issue with JSP 2.1 in your project or maybe Tomcat version in-compatibilty.

**How this was solved:** I installed Windows 7 in dual-boot mode by allocating 100 GB to Windows 7. Installed the IBM software TM1 package(Performance Modeller and BI Insight Tool) in Win7 and everything runs smoothly now.
The IBM Instructors that demonstrated the use of Tm1 Dimensional Modelling also were running Windows 7 in their machines.
I guess - if you wish to solve the problem without going into the details of this exception, You can give this a try!